# Diferença na criação de atributos no Javascript

Tags: javascript, orientação-a-objetos

Qual a real diferença entre criar desses dois jeitos?

```
function Pessoa() {
    this.nome = 'lucas'
}
```

e

```
function Pessoa() {
    nome = 'lucas'
}
```

Na hora de instanciar vai ter alguma diferença?

Comment: É só isso mesmo, ou tem algum outro contexto?

Comment: Sim, terá diferenças, principalmente se você utilizar `Arrow Functions`. Neste caso o `this` varia muito, além disso a variável `nome` poderá ser acessada de qualquer outra função (ela será uma variável global no escopo da função principal, seria o equivalente a um atributo do tipo público em uma classe — você inclusive pode acessar utilizando `myObj.nome`). No segundo exemplo a variável `nome` será local e não poderá ser alterada fora do escopo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem diferença porque as duas coisas são diferentes

Na segunda a variável nome é declarada como uma variável global e no console a nova instância de pessoa é um objeto vazio, a palavra chave `this` serve justamente para especificar a qual contexto aquela variável está, no primeiro caso, as variáveis nome estão no contexto da nova instância daquela função construtora

```js
function Pessoa() {
  nome = 'lucas';
}

console.log(new Pessoa())
```

Um exemplo mais prático:

```js
function Pessoa(n) {
  nome = n
}

let objPessoa1 = new Pessoa('lucas');

console.log(objPessoa1.nome); //undefined
console.log(nome); //lucas

let objPessoa2 = new Pessoa('guilherme');

console.log(objPessoa2.nome); //undefined
console.log(nome); //guilherme
```

Quando é feita a segunda instanciação de Pessoa a função construtora altera a variável global nome, e não criar uma nova que esteja dentro de `objPessoa2`